# Как убрать название headerBackTitle и поменять цвет стрелочки

Tags: react-native

У меня есть навигация в приложение, я хочу убрать название этого тайтла, который показывает на какую страницу мы вернемся нажал по этой стрелке, а также хочу изменить ее цвет (Если тема выбрана по дефолту, то она синяя).
Мне кажется я плохо выразил свои мысли, поэтому приложу скрин того, что я имел ввиду. Заранее извиняюсь, что не смог понятно объяснить. Также вставлю код из своего приложения.

```
<HomeStack.Screen 
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
              title: 'Главная',
              headerBackTitle: 'Главная',
              headerBackTitleStyle: styles.backButton,
              headerRight: () => (
                <View style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row', 
                    width: 50, 
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    marginRight: 0,
                    }}>
                    <Button 
                      type="clear"
                      icon={
                        <Ionicons 
                          name="notifications-outline" 
                          size={24} 
                          color="#46806B"
                        />
                      }
                      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
                    />

                  </View>
              )
          }}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ кодом. Переходим в options и с помощью headerBackTitleVisible отключаем надпись.

```
<HomeStack.Screen 
          name='Notifications'
          component={Notifications}
          options={{
            title: 'Уведомления',
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
           // headerBackTitleStyle: 
            
          }}

        />
```